# XML Multiple Tag Issue Android

Tags: android, xml

I am working with xml and I have come across an issue that I can't get around. I have tags in the xml code that are labeled the same, and i need to pull them all in, but the code that i have at the moment is only pulling in the first tag. The xml code i am trying to parse is:

```
<Pickup>
  <AddressLine>Address Line 1</AddressLine>
  <AddressLine>Address Line 2</AddressLine>
  <AddressLine>Address Line 3</AddressLine>
  <AddressLine>Address Line 4</AddressLine>
  <AddressLine>Address Line 5</AddressLine>
     <Postcode>
        <PostcodeOut>PostCode One</PostcodeOut>
        <PostcodeIn>PostCode Two</PostcodeIn>
     </Postcode>
     <AddressCoords>
        <Latitude>00.000000</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-0.000000</Longitude>
    </AddressCoords>
```

The code i am parsing the data with is:

```
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM
    references = new ArrayList<String>();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Bookings");
    NodeList nlpickup = doc.getElementsByTagName("Pickup");
    NodeList nldestination = doc.getElementsByTagName("Destination");
    NodeList nlAddress = doc.getElementsByTagName("AddressLine");

    AddressData = new StringBuilder();
    addressData = new ArrayList<String>();


    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {              

        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        resultCode = parser.getValue(e, "BookingNo");
        DateTime = parser.getValue(e, "PickupTime");

        Element etwo = (Element) nlpickup.item(i);
        Element eaddress = (Element) nlAddress.item(i);
        PAddressTwo = parser.getValue(eaddress, "AddressLine");

         AddressData.append(PAddressTwo + " ,");

        PPostIn = parser.getValue(etwo, "PostcodeOut");
        PPostOut = parser.getValue(etwo, "PostcodeIn");
        VType = parser.getValue(e, "VehicleType");
        Dist =parser.getValue(e, "Mileage");

        Element ethree = (Element) nldestination.item(i);
        DAddressOne = parser.getValue(ethree, "AddressLine");
        DPostIn = parser.getValue(ethree, "PostcodeOut");
        DPostOut = parser.getValue(ethree, "PostcodeIn");

    }
```

The xml parser that i am using is:

```
public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sbtwo = new StringBuilder();
        String myfeed = null;
        while ((myfeed = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            final String newjsontwo = myfeed.replaceAll(
                    "throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';", "");
            sbtwo.append(newjsontwo);
        }
        is.close();


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){

                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

Any ideas how i get the  tags and where in the code am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have done nothing wrong. Parsing multiple elements is basically what you have done with the Bookings NodeList nl. Get a NodeList from calling getElementsByTagName using the tag name, the Document class and loop through the Nodes within the NodeList using the getLength() method and the item() method of NodeList.

```
NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("AdressLine");
for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
   Node n = nl.item(0);
   // do something with node...
   Element e = (Element)n;
   e.getElementsByTagName("PostCode");
}
```

If a Node object is casted to the Element class, the Element class object allows to access the subelements only of the corresponding Node object. In the code above, the `e.getElementsByTagName("PostCode");` returns only the PostCode subelements of the corresponding AdressLine element.

In your case with the following line of code, you are parsing for example every AdressLine of the whole xml document as you execute the getElementsByTagName method of the Document class. The doc object of the Document class corresponds to the whole document.

```
NodeList nlAddress = doc.getElementsByTagName("AddressLine");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, it does help as it explains a lot. I have tried the code that you stated, before i posted this comment and you are right it does pull in all the address line data, which for me is a pain lol.  I was thinking maybe if i did something like e.getElementsByTagName("Pickup") and passed that to a string, that should get everything that is in pickup and then i could pass that into a doc builder to then get the addresslines of just that one document, think that might work?

Comment: Yes, without trying it by myself, your idea with the document builder and the string will probably work. However, I think it is more efficient to parse a single document. Also, you do not have to build new documents because you can everything do with the original document.

Comment: If my answer is correct, then accept it. I want the points and this how stackoverflow work hehe.

Comment: it partly answers my question lol, i think that there might have been a mis understanding with this, i have just realised that not all the xml code has been copied in. There is <pickup> and <destination> which both hold the same data, just different addresses. The code you gave get all the address lines for both pickup and destination together, I need them separate lol.

Comment: In your example above is no `<destination>` element. If the `<destination>` element comes after `<pickup>` and also contains several `<AdressLine>` elements and you call `doc.getElementsByTagName("AdressLine");` on the whole document, then yes it will return the `<AdressLine>` of `<destination>` and `<pickup>`. If you need them separate, then you have to get first the destination, then the pickup element and get the adressline for each of them like I have explained in my answer (execute `doc.getElementsByTagName("AdressLine");` not on the whole doc but on the pickup and destination element).

Comment: Part 1 of the code:

`NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Pickup");
Node n = nl.item(0);
Element e = (Element)n;
NodeList nlPickupAdressLine = e.getElementsByTagName("AdressLine");

for(int i = 0; i < nlPickupAdressLine.getLength(); i++) {
   Node nn = nlPickupAdressLine.item(0);
   // do something with the adresslines of pickup...   
}`

Comment: Part 2 of the code:
`nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Destination");
n = nl.item(0);
e = (Element)n;
NodeList nlDestinationAdressLine = e.getElementsByTagName("AdressLine");

for(int i = 0; i < nlDestinationAdressLine.getLength(); i++) {
   Node nn = nlDestinationAdressLine.item(0);
   // do something with the adresslines of destination...   
}`